# Dynamic generic type inference for object literals in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, generics, types

In typescript, I can declare a generic function like so:

```
const fn: <T>(arg: T)=>Partial<T>
```

In this case, TypeScript can sometimes infer the type parameter of the function based on the actual parameters I pass it. Is there a similar way to define a generic object literal whose type parameter can be **dynamically inferred** based on its contents? Something like:

```
interface XYZ { 
  obj: <T>{ arr: T[], dict: Partial<T> }
}
```

I am aware I can make the entire interface generic like so:

```
interface XYZ<T> {
  arr: T[],
  dict: Partial<T>
}
```

but I want to avoid that, because then I would have to declare the generic type in advance whenever I am using the interface. For example

```
const x: XYZ
```

will not work. If I want to make the declaration general, I am forced to write:

```
const x: XYZ<any>
```

but this does not allow TypeScript to dynamically infer the specific generic type based on the actual contents of `x`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ah, you want generic values as discussed in [Microsoft/TypeScript#17574](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574).  As you note, they don't exist in the language except in the case of generic functions.  You can go give a  to that issue if you want, or discuss your use case if you think it's helpful.

Given the generic interface

```
interface XYZ<T> {
  arr: T[],
  dict: Partial<T>
}
```

I would just use this workaround: Make a generic function to verify that a value is `XYZ<T>` for *some* `T`, and allow type inference to actually infer `T` whenever it is necessary.  Never try to declare something of type `XYZ`.  Like this:

```
const asXYZ = <T>(xyz: XYZ<T>) => xyz;

const x = asXYZ({
  arr: [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 3, b: 4 }],
  dict: { a: 1300 }
}); // becomes XYZ<{a: number, b: number}>
```

The above usually works for me in practice.  The pro is that it's "natural" TypeScript.  The con is it doesn't represent the "I don't care what type `T` is" properly.

---

If you really want, you could define an [existential type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466).  TypeScript doesn't natively support these, but there is a way to represent it:

```
interface SomeXYZ {
  <R>(processXYZ: <T>(x: XYZ<T>) => R): R
}
const asSomeXYZ = <T>(xyz: XYZ<T>): SomeXYZ => 
  <R>(processXYZ: <T>(x: XYZ<T>) => R) => processXYZ(xyz);
```

The `SomeXYZ` type is a concrete type that doesn't care anymore about `T`, but holds a reference to `XYZ<T>` for *some* T.  You use `asSomeXYZ` to create one from an object:

```
const someXYZ: SomeXYZ = asSomeXYZ({
  arr: [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 3, b: 4 }],
  dict: { a: 1300 }
}); // SomeXYZ
```

And you use it by passing a function that processes the held reference.  That function has to be ready for `XYZ<T>` for any `T`, since you don't know what type of `T` a `SomeXYZ` is holding.

```
// use one
const xyzArrLength = someXYZ((xyz => xyz.arr.length))
```

The `xyzArrLength` is a `number`, since the function `xyz => xyz.arr.length` returns a `number` no matter what `T` is.

Existential types in TypeScript are awkward, since there's a lot of inversion of control going on.  That's the major downside to this, and why I usually go with the less-perfect-but-easier-to-think-about workaround I presented first.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

EDIT:  re-reading your question makes me think you’re actually asking for the answer I listed as a “workaround”.  So, uh... use that?  Cheers.

Comment: Interesting comments and work-arounds; I will try these. I also filed an issue on the TypeScript repo (github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24375), but in light of your pointer to the other issue, I will probably just merge my issue with that

Comment: @jcalz so we can defined some type like this : `type Foo = <T>( param: T ) => T` ? it means type Foo is a function that has a param which type is T and the function return type is also T ? is there any difference with `type Foo<T> = ( param:T ) => T` ?

Comment: @Archsx see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72279919/2887218

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not going to work on an issue in a comment section of a question I answered four years ago.  If you have a new question you should probably post it and then, if I have time, I might take a look at it.  Good luck!

Comment: Well, okay, I lied because I looked.  The whole point of existential generics is that they are opaque to consumers.  If you need access to the type argument that was passed in then you don't want to use existential types.  As for what you *do* want to use, that's something I can't commit to paying much attention to inside a comment section on an old question.  Good luck again!

Answer (score 1):

```
interface MyGenericObjectLiteral<T> {
  arr: T[],
  dict: Partial<T>
}

interface XYZ { 
    obj: MyGenericObjectLiteral<any>
}
```

Interface XYZ here will not be generic, just the subobject MyGenericObjectLiteral. It is actually just what you desired, except that it has a bit different syntax.

Comment: I am aware I can do it this way, but I want to avoid having to make the entire interface generic.

Comment: @Isaev But specifying "any" as the generic type means you lose the dynamic type inference

Comment: @prmph yep. There is no such concept as a generic object literal in typescript. Interfaces are intended to describe the object shape, and they may be generic, but you will have to specify T.

Comment: @ Isaev: But if it works for functions, that means there is no technical reason why it cannot work for objects. TypeScript may not support it now, but it _could_ support it

Comment: @prmph agreed, this is rather a pitfall of TypeScript design than than a logically based thing. One of the worst impressions in my experience of TypeScript usage is constantly trying to guess what should be specified explicitly and what can be inferred automatically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171709/discussion-between-kit-isaev-and-prmph).