# React interdependent prop types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component that takes some props, of which 2 are `A` and `B`. `A` is a function that returns a map of any shape, `B` is a functional component that takes props of the same type that `A` returns. Is there any way to define interdependent prop types like this?

Something like this:

```js
type props = {
  A: (x:string) => T;
  B: (p: T) => React.ReachChild
}
```

I know I can define a generic type `props<T>`, but I wouldn't be able to use it without supplying the type of `T`.

Comment: This scenario may be something Typescript may struggle to compile because it would not recognize which is the correct type if they were different without giving a concrete generic. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @stackoverflow-newbie Ideally it wouldn't need to know which is correct, just whether or not they are equal.

Comment: I went through the Typescript docs (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#hello-world-of-generics and https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) and nowhere I see inference for object/class types specifically. We probably should be looking for an alternative or a workaround.

Comment: Found a similarly asked question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50509952/8109319

Comment: @stackoverflow-newbie I see from that question that this "generic values" functionality is currently being discussed: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is known as `Generic Values` and is not a part of Typescript at the moment, but is currently being discussed: [Typescript Generic Values Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574)

Answer (score 0):

> I know I can define a generic type props,

Yes, you will need to define a generic type.

> but I wouldn't be able to use it without supplying the type of T.

You can use it without supplying if you provide a default (as shown below), but it will default to the value provided (in the example below its `any`):

```
type Props<T = any> = {
  A: (x:string) => T;
  B: (p: T) => React.ReachChild
}
```

Comment: I tried using this method, but TS just uses the default value, any, instead of inferring the narrower type upon use.