# Is there a way to infer a generic type without using a function

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

Is it possible to infer a generic type of value using types only?

For example the type:

```js
interface MyType<T extends string> {
    foo: Record<T, any>,
    bar: Record<string, T>
}
```

You could infer the generic using a function:

```js
function typed<T extends string>(val: MyType<T>) {
    return val;
}
// Works! no typescript diagnostics.
typed({
    foo: { a: null, b: null },
    bar: { whatever: 'a' }
}) // expect MyType<'a'|'b'>
```

is there a type-only syntax that can be inferred without a function? (and of course without specifying the type argument in the generic)

```js
// Does not work! (Generic type 'MyType<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).)
const myType: MyType = {
    foo: { a: null, b: null },
    bar: { whatever: 'a' }
}
```

Comment: Sadly it's not possible at the moment, here's a link to related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50509952/dynamic-generic-type-inference-for-object-literals-in-typescript

Answer (score 8):

No, this is not currently a feature of TypeScript (as of TS 4.4).  You're looking for something like the feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#38349](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38349) which would use the `infer` keyword to ask the compiler to infer a type from context (so you'd say `const myType: MyType<infer>` or something like it).  This request was closed as a duplicate of [microsoft/TypeScript#7481](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7481) which is a longstanding open issue asking for some way to contextually type a value with a type without widening to that type.  In either case it's not something directly supported.  The workaround usually recommended is to create a generic identity function like `typed()`, so what you're doing right now is currently as good as it gets.  Oh well.