# Inferring types from constant object

Tags: typescript

I have the following type structure

```
interface Setting<T> {
  id: string
  default: T
}

interface Section {
  settings: Setting<any>[]
  render: (settings: X) => string
}
```

I am desperately trying to write typings for the above X. In semi-pseudo-typescript-code i am imagining something like this:

```
type X = { [settingId: keyof settings[i]['id']]: typeof settings[i]['default'] }
```

The expected behavior is illustrated below:

```
const section: Section = {
  settings: [
    {
      id: 'description',
      default: 'This is a description'
    }
  ],
  render: (settings) => {
    return `
      <p class="description">
        ${settings.description} <<<--- OK, type: string
        ${settings.foo} <<<--- FAIL, no setting with id 'foo'
      </p>
    `
  }
}
```

As far as i understand it, it should be possible to infer types from constants. Any pointers would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You wrote `Setting[]` in the non-pseudocode part of your example but that's not valid because `Setting` requires a generic type parameter.  What do you want that to be?

Comment: Currently, any will suffice. I fixed the example.

Comment: What you're doing isn't conducive to the sort of inference that TS does by itself.  To get this behavior you will need generics (e.g., `Section<T>` where `T` is the relevant full object type like `{description: string}`) and at least one helper function to get the desired inference.   It could look like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wk0L2w).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to strongly type this, you want to represent both `Setting` and `Section` as being [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `T` of the object type corresponding to the parameter to `render`.

And then to infer a particular `T` from a value of type `Section<T>` we need to use a helper function (so instead of `const x: Section<??> = {...}` you would write `const x = asSection({...})`. There is no way to "infer a type from a `const` object" the way you're asking; see [Is there a way to infer a generic type without using a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69976058/2887218) for more information.

In detail:

---

Your `Setting<T>` would be a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `id`/`default` pairs corresponding to every key in the `T` object type.  You can write this using a *distributive object type* (as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)), which is where you make a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and then immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) it:

```
type Setting<T extends object> = { [K in keyof T]-?:
    { id: K, default: T[K] }
}[keyof T];
```

Let's test that to make sure it works and to demonstrate what it means:

```
interface Foo { a: string, b: number, c: boolean }

type SettingFoo = Setting<Foo>;
/* type SettingFoo = 
     { id: "a"; default: string; } | 
     { id: "b"; default: number; } | 
     { id: "c"; default: boolean; } */
```

See how `Setting<Foo>` is a union of the three possible `id`/`default` pairs?

---

Now we can write `Section<T>` in terms of `T` and `Settings<T>`:

```
interface Section<T extends object> {
    settings: Setting<T>[],
    render: (settings: T) => string
}
```

So for `Foo` this looks like:

```
type SectionFoo = Section<Foo>;
/* type SectionFoo = {
    settings: Setting<Foo>[];
    render: (settings: Foo) => string;
} */
```

---

Now for the helper function and inference.  Unfortunately the simplest version of this doesn't work:

```
const asSection = <T extends object>(s: Section<T>) => s;
```

The problem is that the compiler can't directly infer `T` from `Settings<T>`; it gets the keys, but it loses the values and falls back to `any`:

```
const section = asSection({
    settings: [
        {
            id: 'description',
            default: 'This is a description'
        },
    ],
    render: (settings) => {
        return `
  <p class="description">
    ${settings.description.toOopsieDoodle()} <<<--- wait, no error?
    ${settings.foo} <<<--- FAIL, no setting with id 'foo'
  </p>
`
    }
})
/* const section: Section<{
     description: any; // <-- not what we want
   }> */
```

In the above we have a `Section<{description: any}>` when we want a `Section<{description: string}>` and so `settings.description.toOopsieDoodle()` doesn't result in an error where it should.  Sure, we reject unexpected keys like `settings.foo`, but we want to get value types right.

---

Here's the way I had to do it:

```
const asSection = <S extends { id: K, default: any }, K extends string>(
    s: {
        settings: S[],
        render: (settings: { [U in S as U['id']]: U['default'] }) => string;
    }
): Section<{ [U in S as U['id']]: U['default'] }> => s
```

The idea here is to infer, not the `T` object type, but the `S` type corresponding to `Settings<T>`.  So `S` should be [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `{id: string, default: any}`.  Unfortunately with that constraint the compiler will infer just `string` for the `id` property values instead of the specific [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) for the key names.  So I use a "dummy" generic parameter `K` constrained to `string` to give the compiler a hint that it should preserve the literal type (this is mentioned in [ms/TS#10676](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676) as one of the conditions that prevents the *widening* from the literal type to just `string`).

So now the `s` parameter to the function has a `settings` property of type `S[]`, and the compiler will infer `S` for us nicely.  But we still need `T` as the parameter to the `render` callback and in as the type argument in the `Section<T>` return type.  So we have to compute `T` from `S` (which is `Settings<T>`).  This is what the compiler couldn't do by itself, but luckily we can do it explicitly.

The type is `{ [U in S as U['id']]: U['default'] }`.  What we're doing is [mapping over the union type `S` and remapping its keys](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to be the `id` property.  For each union `U` member of `S`, the key is the `id` property, and the value is the `default` property.

Let's test it out:

```
const section = asSection({
    settings: [
        {
            id: 'description',
            default: 'This is a description'
        },
        {
            id: 'pages',
            default: 100
        }
    ],
    render: (settings) => {
        return `
      <p class="description">
        ${settings.description.toUpperCase()} <<<--- OK, type: string
        ${settings.foo} <<<--- FAIL, no setting with id 'foo'
        ${settings.pages.toFixed(0)} <<<--- OK, type: number
      </p>
    `
    }
})
/* const section: Section<{
    description: string;
    pages: number;
}> */
```

Looks good! The inferred type for `section` is `Section<{description: string; pages: number}>` (I threw another property in there so you could see it work) and the compiler knows that the `settings` callback parameter to `render` is of the type `{description: string; pages: number}`, so the body of that callback type checks as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-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-bTjOcaoDGN0fqo91HAAjAADFD-HGWot5ugST5evlb6-Xi8A-v+gHAaB4GQU573IAh-GCUdmExm9+a4eQVVgJAvgAMI5hAVHieg9EyDKMWdAs9KoGTqEU5pHNc1A0nyYp23lSpwBqSMGmhJ9Y7k+VJDoYDMa00EiC4BARBElD1EhRJ3PSrzpqJCkaS+Dpem4oZagOKZSgWZm-nti5LKjQ5RPe-1qAeVAWsUictuht5zRAA)