Why does TS not support this generic type inference?
interface A<T> {
    a: T
}
let a: A<number> = { a: 1 } // A<number>
let b: A = { a: 1 } // error: A<T> need params

For this code, why do I have to explicitly declare the type of b as A<number> instead of giving this job to the compiler? I think it is reasonable that TypeScript can infer the type of b automatically when I write down only b: A in the editor.
Is this hope reasonable? If unreasonable, why?

Does this answer your question ?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69980011/13491714

This is not possible right now. Here is the open discussion: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32794
