# function types with generics and function expressions

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-systems

Say I have the definition of a generic function that does something to a value of type `T`:

```
function doSomething<T> (t: T): void {
    // do something on a value of type T
    console.log(t);
}
```

Now, I want to capture the type of that function. E.g. a use case might be that I want to use it in further, more complicated types I may plan to define down the road. It's function type could be defined as:

```
type DoSomething<T> = (t: T)=>void
```

So far so good. However nothing in my code, so far, says that `doSomething` is of type `DoSomething`.

Now the problem arises when I want to declare that function `doSomething` indeed is of type `DoSomething`.

If I try to do it in the following way by assigning the value of a function expression to a variable (I know of no other syntax to accomplish this):

```
const doSomething: DoSomething<T> = (t: T): void=>{
  // do something on a value of type T
  console.log(t)
}
```

… then the TypeScript type system complains `Cannot find name 'T'.`

In fact (I think) I do understand why the type system complains as it has no way of inferring what `T` is. What I don't understand is why I didn't have the same problem when `doSomething` was defined equivalently as a function (as opposed to a function expression assigned to a `const`).

Also, how one should properly go about declaring that a function has a given type?

TypeScript Playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEzgZTgWwKZQBYxgDmAPACoB8iAFFAFyJkCUDAbnDMogN4BQviRAHohKOIgDOWXAWKIEiAIaJWigDYhs84IigBPAA5ayAxBARS12AHRq4RWkwDcvAL79%20I3Xi0AjbHYA7ojAijBqErqGWhA%20EADWhES8fIL6RogAIujS%20EnkVAC8NPSMTIUU7Jz8guZgElBiGDh5xAzZzTL5lIjFtAzMbBzIFamCwqKokrmyRPJIyqoaWnA66camtRZwVrb2jqbuHke8QA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the generic type `T` is in the wrong position. You don't want the *type* `DoSomething` to be generic. You want the *function* to be generic.

```
type DoSomething = <T>(t: T) => void

const doSomething: DoSomething = (t): void => {
  console.log(t)
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/FAFwngDgpgBAIgewMoILZRACwJYDsDmMAvDADwAqAfABQgBcM5AlMZTAG4LYAmwwAxglwBnEDG7I0GHAQaIU6LHkIlaTBpx6sYAb2AwYgkQgA2UAHQmE%20NcAC%20QA)

Comment: I am not clear on the distinction. I thought `DoSomething` **was** the type of the function. What's the difference between the type of a function being generic and the function itself being generic?

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus - You should check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72279681/typescript-difference-between-placement-of-generics-arguments