# Typescript omit generic parameter when not needed

Tags: typescript, generics

I've created a generic function type with a return parameter which is entirely dependent on the input parameter types, and the generic parameter has an `extends` clause. Here's a dummy version:

```
type Foo = {}
type MyFunc <T extends Foo> = (a: T, b: T) => T[];

const bar: MyFunc<number> = (a: number, b: number) => [a,b];
const baz: MyFunc<boolean> = (a: boolean, b: boolean) => [a,b];
```

I'm using the generic parameter to ensure 1) `a` and `b` extend `Foo` and 2) `a` and `b` are the same type.

The problem I'm running into is with taking a `MyFunc` as a parameter type. I don't need an exact type for `T`; I only need to ensure the parameter constraints are satisfied when it is called. For example, I'd like to do the following:

```
const makeArray = (qux: MyFunc) => qux(1,2);
```

`1` and `2` are of the same type and both extend `Foo`, so I know the function call will work and I'll get back a `number[]`. However, the above doesn't compile. TypeScript says:

```
Generic type 'MyFunc' requires 1 type argument(s)
```

If I use `(qux: MyFunc<any>)`, then no type-checking at all occurs.

Is there any other syntax I can use to tell TypeScript to check the input parameters but not to require specifying the exact type ahead of time?

Comment: How is TypeScript supposed to know how to check the input parameters if it doesn't know the exact type?

Comment: At the call site, it can simply check that a and b are the same type and that they both implement Foo. That would be enough to make it type-safe, right? Or can you see a situation where this would be unsound?

Comment: So are you really just asking for default generic parameters? `type MyFunc<T extends Foo = Foo>`

Comment: You probably want to make `makeArray` generic too and pass this generic type to `MyFunc` like `const makeArray = <T extends Foo>(qux: MyFunc<T>) => qux(1,2)`.

Comment: This looks like a confusion about generic type parameter scope.  Maybe you are looking for something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2p4bm) where `qux`'s type is actually generic.  If that's not what you're looking for, could you spell out exactly what you mean?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, that's exactly what I needed, thank you! Just had to move the <...> portion to the right side of the equals sign so that T gets specified at call-time instead of definition time. If you write it up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've got the scope of the generic type parameter wrong.  There are two distinct (but related) "flavors" of generics in TypeScript.  See [TypeScript how to create a generic type alias for a generic function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62720954/2887218) and [typescript difference between placement of generics arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72279681/2887218) for example.

There are generic *types*, where the type parameter is declared on the type name itself, like

```
// type GenType<T> = ...T...
```

And there are generic *functions*, where the type parameter is declared on the *call signature*, like

```
// type GenFunc = <T>(...T...)=>...
```

You originally had `MyFunc` as a generic type that evaluates to a non-generic function

```
// original
type MyFunc<T extends Foo> = (a: T, b: T) => T[];
```

but that doesn't seem to be what you want.  Instead, you should make it a non-generic type that evaluates to a generic function:

```
// changed
type MyFunc = <T extends Foo>(a: T, b: T) => T[];
```

---

So now you can make a function of type `MyFunc` and it will act like your old `MyFunc<T>` for every possible `T`:

```
// actually generic
const foo: MyFunc = (a, b) => [a, b];
```

If you really want to restrict the function so that it takes some specific type argument, you can use [instantiation expressions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions):

```
const bar = foo<number>; 
// const bar: (a: number, b: number) => number[]
const baz = foo<boolean>; 
// const baz: (a: boolean, b: boolean) => boolean[]
```

But I don't know how useful that is.

---

Anyway, now you can implement `makeArray` how you want it, where `MyFunc` does not require a type argument:

```
const makeArray = (qux: MyFunc) => qux(1, 2);
// const makeArray: (qux: MyFunc) => number[]
```

And look, the compiler infers that the return type of `makeArray` is `number[]`, as desired!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAVAFgSygZQhMOALgE4jADmEKA9gLLIDeAUE0m0oQJ4zIBi11JAF4kDAL6t2XHklqdeAV2DwAPCiQQAHoQjAAJlCT9qAPmFIAFCABcqADRIARrZQBKYWZQBtALoBuFnYkAHpgpAw9XUIMeBAAGzjOcLAYOPwoiD0kEEIkYiVoyCcFXOJoEhidLMJBACsFKFzgBTBHCGJgxwE0smykeGoUjDSODEgAOkmkAHc0TgB+STYB4EanEGJbOUVlFWbW9rMRK1t9tuIHZyQz9vchMy8QS-8l-upV3McQAC8t+SVVF1qD1gEdLDYnN0IGRLrYgSC7g8nk4XkwJExpHwBOZxExQkgoAMZNQAGYcNDITFIOCkSA6YhIMDUABu0A4gkIFP68TiBIw5FAhAUZQx3GQ2wB5jUGm0ugMRgEJhO9icLkRqF8ATxYQQQp5SUowHaMSYKzWJIEfx28HMVku6sezy1Zs+G3MFuoexa5xMfhCYQwZM41AUeWhCSS0zIuRqYcaxEq5OQGGAMBKUG1bw+6024NO3vasOuBeI6puxF8pveay+33dAhU8OhoL9+L0GEINUzLvWvzzkOBzaLTbI6pHwErmeA1GmSGDodiwBmCZ05KwSDQM7nIZm0ar2bAIAA1hAAILEUhJY4ARwUmitAPVt80FgAjA4AEyuAL4nuHk-npetgWM+D7KGWJaTv+Z4XiAnAWB637+kg1BHnBTDQYBcEWF8patmE7TENQFxOBAsQNJSXIbOQLRROEhhKCAjgjLGUA5FgJJJJyyCGsaNpAA)