# What does this TypeScript generic syntax mean?

Tags: typescript

I recently came across a type definition like:

```js
type Generic<T> = T
type NotGeneric = <T>(x: T) => T
```

I managed to make use of it like:

```js
const generic: Generic<string> = ''
const notGeneric: NotGeneric = <T>(x: T) => x

const stringResult = notGeneric('')
const numberResult = notGeneric(0)
...
```

What does the `<T>` prefix for the `NotGeneric` type do? It seems like it forces the TypeScript compiler to infer the type `T` from `x`.

Comment: It's just normal generic syntax. It doesn't _force_ the compiler to use `x`, you can still do e.g. `const fooResult = notGeneric<string>("foo")`.

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72279681/2887218) and its answer fully address your issue? Or is something missing?

Comment: @jcalz thanks, yes. Ive been doing typescript for two years and never saw this syntax!