# How to describe a generic anonymous function in terms of a generic type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

First, some code:

```js
type SimpleFunction<I, O> = (input: I) => O;

const mySimpleFunction: TypeX = <T, U>(arg: T) => U = { /* ... */ };
```

In the above code snippet, is it possible to describe `TypeX` in terms of `SimpleFunction`?

As examples of what I'm after, the following are a couple examples of attempts that do not work:

1. Attempt #1:

   ```js
   const mySimpleFunction1: SimpleFunction<T, U> = <T, U>(arg: T) => U = { /* ... */ };
   ```

   **Error** `TS2304: Cannot find name 'T'.`

   **Issue** `T` and `U` are not within the lexical scope in which `T` and `U` are defined (that being the anonymous function definition itself -- basically anything after the first equals sign).
2. Attempt #2:

   ```js
   const mySimpleFunction2: <T, U>SimpleFunction<T, U> = <T, U>(arg: T) => U = { /* ... */ };
   // and the following (both share the same issue):
   const mySimpleFunction3: <T, U> SimpleFunction<T, U> = <T, U>(arg: T) => U = { /* ... */ };
   ```

   **Error** `TS1005: '(' expected.`

   **Issue** The TypeScript compiler appears to be expecting the opening paren of a function definition parameter list.
3. Attempt #3:

   ```js
   const mySimpleFunction4: <T, U>(SimpleFunction<T, U>) = <T, U>(arg: T) => U = { /* ... */ };
   ```

   **Error** `TS7051: Parameter has a name but no type. Did you mean 'arg0: SimpleFunction'?`

   **Issue** Again, this further reinforced my belief that the compiler expects anything in this format to be a function definition.
4. Attempt #4:

   ```js
   const <T, U>mySimpleFunction5: SimpleFunction<T, U> = <T, U>(arg: T) => U = { /* ... */ };
   ```

   **Error** `TS1134: Variable declaration expected.`

   **Issue** No type information is expected before the colon the follows the variable name.

I understand that it is possible to simply omit that type and let the compiler infer it from the arguments, but that is not what I am trying to accomplish here -- I want to be able to use this pattern for more complex types so that the compiler will catch type issues within the function definition if and when they occur.

Is what I am trying to do possible? If so, how?

The other question is a basic question about how generics work, this question is in regards to a specific subset of the overall field of generics -- value generics.

Comment: TS's type system isn't expressive enough to represent the transformation you're trying to do. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72279919/2887218) for more information.  Specifically you'd need something like "generic values" as requested in [ms/TS#17574](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574), or a Haskell-like `forall` quantifier, so that you could say `<T, U>SimpleFunction<T, U>` and have it work.  Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer (or close as a dupe of the other); if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, that answers my question. I was hoping that because I could flatten the type and use something like `const mySimpleFunction2: <T, U>(arg: T) => U = <T, U>(arg: T) => U = { /* ... */ };`, that there was some way of representing this with the type alias that I just wasn't aware of, but alas...