# How to define a typescript function with a generic function parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to pass a 'generic' function as parameter to a function without 'specialising' the function at that time. Something like:

```
type F<T> = (p: T) => void

function report(f: F) {
  f<A>({ a: 1 })
  f<B>({ b: "foo" })
}
// with
type A = { a: number }
type B = { b: string }
```

This obviously doesn't work. I wonder if what I would need here is related to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213?

The reason for wanting to do this, is to ensure that was is being passed to `f` is
indeed of the specific type provided. The function itself doesn't really care. Actually,
in my real use case, both `A` and `B` would extend the same type (the only part `f` requires).

My current workaround is using an interface:

```
interface I {
  f<T>(p: T): void
}

function report2(i: I): void {
  i.f<A>({ a: 1 })
  i.f<B>({ b: "foo" })
}
```

or a helper function:

```
function ensure<T>(arg: T): T {
  return arg
}

function report3(f: (arg: any) => void): void {
  f(ensure<A>({ a: 1 }))
  f(ensure<B>({ b: "foo" }))
}
```

Is there any way to declare this more directly?

Comment: What if you just define type F = () => <T>(p:T)=>void

Comment: Yes! I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use **generic function** instead of **generic type**

Compare genric function:

```ts
type F = <T>(p: T) => void

//equivalent to:
interface FInterface {
  <T>(arg: T): void;
}
```

with generic type

```ts
type F<T> = (p: T) => void

// equivalent to
interface FInterface<T> {
  (arg: T): void;
}
```

In the first case we have a generic function, in the second a non-generic function as a part of a generic interface

See: [typescript difference between placement of generics arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72279681/typescript-difference-between-placement-of-generics-arguments)

> **Generic fuction**
> A generic function declares its generic type parameter (or parameters) on the call signature of the function:
>
> ```ts
> type IdentityGenFunc = <T>(t: T) => T
> ```
>
> The type parameter on a generic function (T above) isn't specified until the function is actually called, at which point the caller specifies it (or the compiler infers it on behalf of the caller). This means that a generic function implementation must be able to deal with any possible specification of T that the function caller wants

See also: [Generic Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-types)

In your case, where A and B extend same type, you can limit the arguments of F only to that base type:

```ts
type F = <T extends Base>(p: T) => void
```

Entire example:

```ts
type Base = {id: number}
type A = { a: number } & Base
type B = { b: string } & Base


type F = <T extends Base>(p: T) => void

function report(f: F) {
  f<A>({ id: 1, a: 1 })
  f<B>({ id: 2, b: "foo" })
}

function ff(p: Base) {
  console.log(p);
}

report(ff);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need the type parameter (`T`) attached to the function signature, not to the type constructor (`F`) itself:

```
type F = <T>(p: T) => void

function report(f: F) {
  f<A>({ a: 1 })
  f<B>({ b: "foo" })
  //f<B>({ b: 0 })  // ERROR as expected
  //f<B>({ c: 0 })  // ERROR as expected
}
// with
type A = { a: number }
type B = { b: string }

report((a) => a);  // just an example
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYlC8UA8AVAfACjALiiglAmlAG4D2AlgCYBQNAZgK4B2AxsBWc1AE4RhkewDPVwxCAbxpQo9JAEFMEqAENcARigBffNNlIAQkqgAjXACJ6ZMue26ZAegdyjGZWagAGO44dQAogBKgQDygaoAzlAQAB6Q7BC0vi7GrLjeOr4BwWGR0XEQCbRaNE5QAO4UwAAWNKCQUPIIUMpqUMyMALYmEDzadeDQBs3uuBHAPBTMAOb9NHwCQhgYKoTwxKsA3FkAVozjqtyxKp1gADYQNEA)