# TypeScript reusable function signature with generics syntax

Tags: typescript, function, generics, syntax

Hi I was wondering what the best syntax was for a reusable function type (same parameters, return type, reusable by multiple functions) and generics?

I couldn't figure out a shorter syntax then:

```
type CountResult<T extends object> = (arg: T) => [T, number]

function log<T extends object>(arg: T){
    console.log(arg)
}

function countWithKeys<T extends object>(arg: Parameters<CountResult<T>>[0]): ReturnType<CountResult<T>> {
    const count = Object.keys(arg).length
    log<T>(arg) // Need to be able to access T
    return [arg, count]

}

function countWithLoop<T extends object>(arg: Parameters<CountResult<T>>[0]): ReturnType<CountResult<T>>{
    let count = 0;
    for(const i in arg) {
        count++;
    }
    log<T>(arg)
    return [arg, count]
}
```

I'm basically asking what's the best syntax to reuse the type signature of a generic function.

Comment: I'm confused about the goal here, but there is no shorthand syntax for function statements; you could use function expressions instead, and make `Identity` an actual generic *function* type (by giving `T` the proper scope), which gives [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WPMGqw).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could maybe write up an answer explaining; if not, please [edit] to clarify your use case.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [Instantiation Expressions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions)? [Example](https://tsplay.dev/mqqOJm)

Comment: Maybe Identity isn't a good example cause both of the copy-cat functions needs to be also be generics and Identity you can figure out the generics by the passed in arguments.

Comment: ```
type IdentityPlus<T, U> = (arg: T) => U;
```

How about something like this? Syntax for 2 generic functions that match this signature.

Comment: Please put your new example in the question itself, and would you mind letting me know if my approach from the first comment does or does not meet your needs?  I can't tell if you're responding to me or just to the comment after it

Comment: @QuangVan Are you looking for something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpKqgN)?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz and @jsejcksn I updated the question to include a better example. I don't think y'all answers does exactly what I want, which is to still use `<T>` in the two derived functions.

Comment: The two new functions will also be generic functions. It won't narrow the generic in anyway.

In the same file, I am just having two functions that does the same thing, so the same generic function signature. (It'll just do the thing in different ways) and the consumer of the module will have a choice, for example to use LoDash or Underscore.

Comment: ① Your new example has errors in the implementation (`arg` in both cases is not suitable for the functions you're passing them into), and apparently depends on third-party libraries?  Could you please instead provide a [mre] that doesn't introduce problems and complications unrelated to your question? ② In both examples you have seem to be putting the generic type parameter in the wrong scope. If I fix that, [as shown in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N5j2Pm), the problem you're asking about goes away.  Does this work for your needs or not? Let me know how to proceed.

Comment: ```
const lodashSize: SizeFn = arg => { 
  const result: T = lodash.size(arg)    
  return T
}
```

I need to be able to use T. When I try to in the example you gave @jcalz I get error "Cannot find name 'T'"

Comment: `return T`?  What are you doing?  Why would `lodash.size(arg)` return anything but `number`?  If you want `T` in there you can write `<T,>(arg) => { ⋯ }` but I'm starting to get weary of pseudocode/typos because it's very hard to see through it to understand your intent.

Comment: > In both examples you have seem to be putting the generic type parameter in the wrong scope.

Yes this is part of my problem, I don't know the right/best syntax for this, the only syntax I can come up with is to use `Parameters` and `ReturnType` utility type on both functions to match the type.

I tried fat-arrow and `function` declaration but can't figure out a better syntax than the one in my question (with Parameters and ReturnType) which works but thought there was a better syntax out there that was more DRY.

Comment: I'm going to disengage until such time as the question is [edit]ed to take into account the issues I have raised earlier in my previous comments. If that doesn't happen, that's fine, but I won't respond unless that does occur.  Good luck!

Comment: The Identity and SizeFn are two separate examples... I am trying to reuse a generic function type signature without narrowing the generic. So 2 functions have the SAME generic function type signature, and I want to know what is the best, shortest, idiomatic syntax to do that.

Comment: @jcalz I updated my question with a better example. Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: [This](https://tsplay.dev/wXgkDW) is the best, shortest, idiomatic syntax for your new example.  I see in your comments you have said "I need to be able to use T" along with pseudocode.  I *might* assume at this point that you don't actually need this because you have yet to show a [mre] that demonstrates the use case... surely your requirements would be represented in your question by now, right?  If you *do* need that then you either annotate the call signature manually or use `typeof arg` to extract the type you care about, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/w1L48W).

Comment: Does that suffice and I can write up an answer? Or is there still something missing?

Comment: https://tsplay.dev/WKb78m reflects the latest edits.  Please let me know whether I should write up an answer using this as a basis, or if I should disengage.

Comment: Thanks for all the help jcalz. 

type CountResult = <T extends object>(arg: T) => [T, number]

function log<T extends object>(arg: T){
    console.log(arg)
}
const countWithKeys: CountResult = <T extends object>(arg: T) => {    
    const count = Object.keys(arg).length
    log<T>(arg);
    return [arg, count]

}

Doesn't seem so DRY to me but at least I know there isn't something more obvious I'm missing. Thanks for all the help. TypeScript is strict and stingy. Do you have recommended reading on how to get better at TypeScript?

Answer (score 1):

The scope of your [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter is incorrect, or at least not conducive to being used for your purpose.  A generic *function* has the type parameter on the *call signature* (like `type F = <T>(t: T)=>void`) whereas you had a generic *type* with the parameter on the *type name* (like `type F<T> = (t: T)=>void`).  Those are different; see [typescript difference between placement of generics arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72279681/2887218) for more discussion.

The type you really want is this:

```
type CountResult = <T extends object>(arg: T) => [T, number]
```

---

To give `countWithKeys` and `countWithLoop` that type, you'll need to change from using a [`function` *statement*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) to a function *expression* (such as a [`function` expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) or an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)).

That's because we can't currently directly *annotate* function statements in TypeScript.  There's an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#22063](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22063) to support function statement annotations, but for now they're unfortunately not part of the language.

So let's use arrow functions:

```
const countWithKeys: CountResult = arg => {    
    const count = Object.keys(arg).length
    log(arg);
    return [arg, count]
}

const countWithLoop: CountResult = arg => {    
    let count = 0;
    for (const i in arg) {
        count++;
    }
    log(arg);
    return [arg, count]
}
```

That compiles without error, and the `arg` type parameter is [contextually](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) given the appropriate generic type.  Looks good, we're all done here.

---

Well, except that you apparently need to refer to the generic type parameter `T` within the implementations of the functions.  Your example is that you want to be able to call `log<T>(arg)` instead of `log(arg)`.  This is absolutely not necessary, since the compiler will happily infer the type argument for you.  But in order to proceed, let's *pretend* that `log(arg)` wouldn't work and that you do need `log<T>(arg)`.  Presumably there's a more persuasive use case in the real code.

Anyway, in the above function implementations, the type argument you want is *anonymous* and you can't use it directly.  To address that you need to give that type a name somehow.  The most straightforward but verbose approach is to explicitly and fully annotate the implementation, including the relevant type parameter declaration:

```
const countWithKeys: CountResult = <T extends object>(arg: T) => {    
    const count = Object.keys(arg).length
    log<T>(arg);
    return [arg, count]   
}
```

Another approach is to attempt to get a reference to the anonymous type in some other way.  For `CountResult`, the `arg` parameter is of the relevant type, so you can use [the `typeof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html):

```
const countWithLoop: CountResult = arg => {    
    type T = typeof arg;
    let count = 0;
    for (const i in arg) {
        count++;
    }
    log<T>(arg);
    return [arg, count]
}
```

This is a bit less verbose, but is harder to generalize and potentially more confusing.

There's no "perfect" approach here; you either need to let the compiler infer things for you, thereby making them anonymous, or you need to explicitly specify and annotate these things, thereby making them potentially redundant.  This is about as good as it gets.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gVwHbAEoQM4IDbCgXigB4AVKCAD2AiQBMMo4AjAKwgGNgA+ACgEMATgHMAXFBIBKAlygBtEgBooSBAFsmEAQF0AUDoBmyTgEs4SKNjhDS5KjXqNWHbv2FjJAbx1QfUdmYw4bAgAOkshVyEJHQBfHX8kDDx-ZGAAdWNgAAsAaQgQDDF4VPQsXAJiMkpqOgZmNk5eQVFxKXwZD18ob18EpL9EFAqAeSdOEIBrfIxIiTCaIWyen3DSJuEJAG5lqAEIYAQBc1lmpRSUXVi9PuTB9MysgBk4ODAiu9KcPEJm6ShO3w7UCQcQVYEQOD6KDNbZdYK3VIVAAMsN8+jgAigPBuUGMuPMzSkXi6XXOwAA1OTUT44nCrGtZtTdvtDsdTgNUroYkA)

Comment: jcalz, thank you for the follow-up detailed answer, very educational. I'm gonna read it carefully and try some things out to see if I can get something better than `Parameters` and `ReturnType`. I'll leave a follow-up comment once I do this. Thank you!