# How can I type this function properly so that it errors when the correct arguments aren't supplied

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an in-memory cache function which you can pass a function and its arguments to that will cache the results. The function itself works but I can't figure out how create the generic type signature so that I get errors if I call the cache with a function but not the arguments that the function requires. Here is a minimal example:

```
type AnyFunc = (...args: any[]) => any;

type MemCache<T extends AnyFunc> = {
  (fn: T, ...args: Parameters<T>): ReturnType<T>;
  debug: () => void;
};

function makeCache<T extends AnyFunc>(): MemCache<T> {
  const cache = {};

  function queryCache<T extends AnyFunc>(fn: T, ...args: Parameters<T>): ReturnType<T> {
    return fn(...args)
  }

  queryCache.debug = () => {
    console.log(cache)
  };

  return queryCache;
}

const memcache = makeCache()

const fn = (num: number, str: string) => 'hello'

//@ts-expect-error
const res = memcache(fn) // should error because 3 arguments are expected but received 1

//@ts-expect-error
res.then() // should error because fn returns a string, not a promise
```

You can also see the example in the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAQQHYQGIFckGM4F44AUAdCQIYBOA5gM4BccpKA2gLoCUeAfAygNyihIsOAFkYAWwDCpLAAsYAHgAqcGAA8wMJABNqiFBmzd8Ab1BxCAMyT0lAGjgkiFGvQAKFUuJiby1ZZxs9ABKPujkSErQikqc-CAW2jAARuiU9AQcuNwAbgD2AJba8QC+8aCWmFhgBXlIcOKkANYw0nIxqhpauvpoVZyZ9GJSMvIBcGYJcFh11GDTo-CmZQJTldg1dXAAjugw5BBtYyrqmjp6yH1GBNa2Dk4udHAe5F4++-6xQXChYOGR0XGkwsFnIYQicGsxDIVGobHMcBKqwsu32h0WRCSqUoeEIWW4wJBMyQ1DyABsYEQyXlKAQsIt4VMViAEWC-hDUQcjjBSqtiXMGhJ6e1cY0WtzMnzZvNrLiCEh0OJ6ArxMl9g45uR6JqCkhKPi4AByeRk6mG1YAegtAAEwNQALTqWDVR3kch5cigfnzMF6fDecTC+Q3JAcK1waiyPLoMnaVRuj1wNX09DUeAAZgYVEVWjtWfgTpg1RgcdSPqLMAKORLcAAjJabXbHWpnWBXe7PSBfUQwPIkJk4OHI9HY-GO0mi6RU-BZWz-npSBGwORdZQHEg8vNF1B3eICmmgA).

I have tried extracting the inner function (`queryCache`) and calling that separately and the compiler errors as expected. The issue appears to be the outer function but I need that because that gets called when the module loads to instantiate the cache which the `queryCache` function closes over.

Comment: I don't understand why `MemCache` is generic; presumably you don't actually mean that and just want the call signature to be generic, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mpzD7w). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Ah, yes, this is the solution, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T` in `MemCache` is inappropriately scoped.  You've applied it at the top level, to the whole `MemCache` type, whereas it really belongs only on the call signature:

```
type MemCache = {
  <T extends AnyFunc>(fn: T, ...args: Parameters<T>): ReturnType<T>;
  debug: () => void;
};
```

See [typescript difference between placement of generics arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72279681/2887218) for a detailed description about why such things make a difference.  In short, you want a `MemCache` to be able to handle any `T` that the *caller* wants, not just a particular one chosen by the *implementer* of `MemCache`.  Anyway, now `makeCache()` looks like

```
function makeCache(): MemCache {
  const cache = {};

  function queryCache<T extends AnyFunc>(
    fn: T, ...args: Parameters<T>): ReturnType<T> {
    return fn(...args)
  }

  queryCache.debug = () => {
    console.log(cache)
  };

  return queryCache;
}
```

And when you call it you get the behavior you expect:

```
const memcache = makeCache()
const fn = (num: number, str: string) => 'hello'
const res = memcache(fn) // err!
// Expected 3 arguments, but got 1
res.then() // err!
// Property 'then' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAjgTwiBAVAMlA5gSwDsAFAQxlIFsQ4QYBnBAXgQG9gEEBXeuwqkAC4E9ODCK4A3BwRQ4ACzowQARy75lAEwjkqw0eMJSZUCHHxR+AGx0VKwwl0oAjOtIC+wUJFiIUaTBxcKC44MjsaOkYWdk5NGlJ8K3oAMVgggkIAeVD9MQkPLy9waHgkVHQMAGU4UloAWVIIZjYZKzwiYWwOkl1qWgZpTnbg3MC8ELC+yMHgd2kvf3QAUU18KbtomVYEAG0AaQQiBABrEGQoADNMGrqQRogAXWFdpeF9gBoEEEIxZC7bg0mgdHo8EO5dmcLtdqrUgU9gAB6ABU5QCq3W4So0QQMk4ezeCAARCMiESvj8-l0gkQsf0omCAD64-GcV4VYQkiahcnfX4wf7jUYbAQDehg4DIxFeADGllE3zWcGEAAoAHQa9loCn85DPBAYkWUegASmYAD4EAA3KD4TQtFVLHV-M1MS2xEQAd3WMvkCEdFTNHs4MtIvGJpMIROEwfxcsICogMFMLUpArVPD4AiGrIQzmUpBOOc4nhLXk8SMRCFIoSgcsoECskQQntgJ0YimUsvliGU9C4VkQLBASpVXMyvJ2mZg-GonNoogAjAAmADMvLkneUag0I9semJC7gG7MFms+-sCBXq-BJoWQA)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, this is very helpful.