# Inferring a generic parameter from a function passed as argument

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

I have a function which accepts adapters and their options as an optional argument.

```
// One type of query adapter
type O1 = { opt: 1 }
const adapter1 = (key: string, options?: O1) => 1
// Second type of query adapter
type O2 = { opt: 2 }
const adapter2 = (key: string, options?: O2) => 2
// There can be hypothetically any kind of query adapters, but they adhere to this general format
```

As said in the comment, there can be hypothetically infinite amount of adapters *(hence  the adapter consuming function needs to accept a generic argument)*. But the adapters do always have their `Parameters` in the comon format of

`[string, options?: unknown (generic)]`

Here is the definition of the adapter consuming function:

```
// type definition helper for the adapter
type Fn = <O, R>(key: string, options?: O) => R

// 'consumer' function which accepts these adapters and their options as an optional argument
const query = <F extends Fn, O extends Parameters<F>[1]>(
  key: string,
  adapter: F,
  options?: O
): ReturnType<F> => adapter(key, options)
```

I would expect typescript to correctly infer the `options` based on the passed arguments, that's however not the case:

```
// These should pass (omitted optional config)
query('1', adapter1)
query('2', adapter2)

// These should pass as well (with config applied)
query('1config', adapter1, { opt: 1 })
query('2config', adapter2, { opt: 2 })

// These should throw error due to config type mismatch
query('1error', adapter1, { foo: 'bar' })
query('2error', adapter2, { foo: 'bar' })
```

However all of these throw a TS error due to mismatch on the passed adapter arguments.
With the following error:

```bash
Argument of type '(key: string, options?: O1) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Fn'.
  Types of parameters 'options' and 'options' are incompatible.
    Type 'O | undefined' is not assignable to type 'O1 | undefined'.
      Type 'O' is not assignable to type 'O1 | undefined'.
```

Now in the example this could be fixed by changing `O` to `O extends O1 | O2 | undefined`, but as mentioned in the question, there can be hypotehtically infinite variations in the adapter options, but I still need my consumer function to correctly infer the option object to provide type safety when the user types the `query` function and specifies the `options` object.

> *The real issue is bit more complex with callbacks, but this is the minimal reproducible example that does nicely describe the issue. Please don't comment on how it's nonsensical to not use `(key, options) => adapter(key, options)` for invocation directly, as it's outside the scope of the question.*

Here's the [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHkDsFNQFwJ4AdYHsBmoCOBXaAnBUAQwBNik4CAoRFCARlAF5QBvUVSgLlCYF9qAY1SQAznBLlKBJqwAUAa2gJeE-AEtIAcwA0nShtFiA-L3AMAlCwB8faiFABlaCMil4yNJlwEiZCip8Wi8IACYWdgM4XgjBNwkpQIIIhWVVUHUtPWijcTNw62Y7MIcwABUACwJYIWJIUAAjWErkVDhquA06gBse-0giRS0PDGw8QiSZfDF9RpxJDpUpavxYOFR4So0xUG1oGHxiHtB0VHwAW2I4ajLQADlUAHdQVdgdrdgAchE1r9OcJAhF1RKAntshJUSEIhNBKLslmJYAFprt6h4kO0Dl1jv1Php8LljCQ0Q0uCDIMcSPhtDgLtiQvQAGINVgAHnA+gASjYlCo1HBNDp9OS8qZzEU7FzhMZJL5JuymaBoAAPKjuXYs-TgZVqg6kXYABWIR3pQTEbKZNgA2gwALq89ICoU5FFBXhMkWGYwFcCWXhc6BwHD4SDlLyWuzFKZBPkIL0UsSWW6OKrQJGZSqoHA9DHEMS7eSoC4aOBUUbeyknNzoDTaZPyhDyL4ML76N2yBsTJtfMJtmMpZN3NMZsRZnN5gsksHQPqgeRPUtQmt1khIJA9DTQUhdvzNhgr7T9jv4Bj6Djk3gCXeEZthQ-H6RBMLn6KxUD8Iep6qj8e5rb4M8yr4IBhKkHg8CbIenj0CWYhXHAkLUI2+4EKBj7JKer5nKgvBfI0Jr-J+yHdneaHnBh0wvlEOF4QR+BEcmQA) for you to experiment on

Comment: @jcalz yeah that does seem to do the trick. I see you changed the generic inferred function type arguments to have type accept the two type arguments instead, but it still would be helpful to me *(and hopefully others)* if you could elaborate a to why this makes a difference in an answer. Thanks! :)

Comment: @jcalz actually could you do me a favor, and in the answer include how to go about this in nested functions? Because the fix does work 1 level deep, but as soon as I nest it with 1 level deeper. i.e. a function called `schema` which accepts array of invoked `query`  which pass along the `option` argument it breaks the type inferrence again. Not sure if you need me to include an another example or it's clear what I'm talking about from the comment.

Comment: @jcalz Fair enough, actually feel free to finnish up your answer (especially if you have anything already written not to waste your time), then I might be able to figure out the rest from there and if not i'll post a new one in the future, as I believe there is a merit to the question as it stands in it's current form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that your `Fn` type has the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters in the wrong scope.  Your `Fn` means that the *caller* of an `Fn` can choose `O` and `R` and the implementation has to be able to handle any choice the caller makes.  Neither `adapter1` nor `adapter2` behave that way.  Instead you should write

```
type Fn<O, R> = (key: string, options?: O) => R
```

which means that the *implementer* chooses `O` and `R` and the caller of `Fn<O, R>` can only use those specific choices.  See [typescript difference between placement of generics arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72279681/2887218) for more information about generic type parameter scope issues.

So you can change `Fn` to `Fn<any, any>` in your `query()` (and remove the unnecessary `O` type parameter) and it will start working as expected:

```
const query = <F extends Fn<any, any>>(
    key: string, adapter: F, options?: Parameters<F>[1]
): ReturnType<F> => adapter(key, options)

query('1', adapter1) // okay
query('2', adapter2) // okay
query('1config', adapter1, { opt: 1 }) // okay
query('2config', adapter2, { opt: 2 }) // okay
query('1error', adapter1, {}) // error, opt is missing
query('2error', adapter2, { foo: 'bar' }) // error, foo is unexpected
```

That's the answer to the question as asked, but there is a secondary issue I want to bring up:

---

You're using the [`Parameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) and [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) utility types with a generic parameter.  These utility types are implemented as [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), and the compiler is very bad about type checking generic conditional types.  It won't notice, for example, that this is a problem:

```
const badQuery = <F extends Fn<any, any>>(
    key: string, adapter: F, options?: Parameters<F>[1]
): ReturnType<F> => adapter(key, 389398) // no error!!
```

For the example code here it's much better to just make `query()` generic in `O` and `R` directly, instead of trying to tease that informatin out of `F`:

```
const query = <O, R>(
    key: string, adapter: Fn<O, R>, options?: O
): R => adapter(key, options);
```

This behaves the same from the caller's side, but now it will catch problems in the implementation as well:

```
const badQuery = <O, R>(
    key: string, adapter: Fn<O, R>, options?: O
): R => adapter(key, 389398); // error as expected
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHkDsFNQFwJ4AdYHsBmoCOBXaAnBUAQwBNik4CAoRFCARlAF5QBvUVSgLlCYF9qAY1SQAznBLlKBJqwAUAa2gJeE-AEtIAcwA0nShtFiA-L3AMAlCwB8faiFABlaCMil4yNJlwEiZCip8Wi8IACYWdgM4XgjBNwkpQIIIhWVVUHUtPWijcTNw62Y7MOoQ+gAxSAAecH0AJTs0lTU4TR19Ljg803Miu3qyyGIAW2gxJGIhWAANdmpQRdAEyV9CSOqK0GgADyp3MVAq6uJIBH1ThBsbeQWl+-TW9pyAmXxeCs7DYwKABWJ8KNoEExJsbABtBgAXTui0svHqwJw+EgABUvGDbEk3koVF9usZLGVYctjJIAEZkACKeHWrE22z20AORxqlwuZ2ut3uDxamTa2Qu0iCH3xPT+AKBILBkJh93hoERcGRaIxFSadleQVx51AAGYABwATj1RoN1kckFQ23w+FQ+FAAHcABbEOAmACEZXuawQ8gA5Ax-ULkvgrKBHKhFMQECTfQGwsHsUEwhawFGY3HaX7A250BptEmtbJ9BwurwBGnONHYz7swm8wWi8KUqXorFQPwqxna0t44GCHb8M3QwxS12I2BB-b8aANIcRvOxNks34E9PhyG3mE2+hUKheP7KcPO1WN-o99b56AcDAdighFRSGVBNRhmMJlNYABNeb3FbYNmGx1IqNwkryGRZB0yYEB8NQgY0Yo-OYJIKvUWLFvgOpIeIlgANyTtWmYkgBlKkDSfjAQ0YE8ksjz8s8W4iqytTUThvQQKhCIYS2WHpPohomma+GERuJCHLsD5PsSdZroGI5vOGkY1quhAJgpKbdipslqbmoj5oWTEllE5Z8KehE9qpOZhI2hkwfgO4mTwoBxFpmY6TmDAbhpxlsBOjjntEc4LkuK4eeutr2j5Dm7vuh7Hv65kBZF+AXvuwU3neUnQM+-BAA)